# How do I make my USB mouse work with my wireless adapter?

Tags: usb, wireless, mouse

**UPDATE**

At some point, this started working after a kernel/firmware update, so it's not really a valid question any more (or else, the solution is "update your RPi")

---

**Original question**

I have a **Raspberry Pi Model B** running **Raspbian**, and I have an **EDIMAX wireless adapter** as well as an **IOGEAR USB mouse**. Both of them work fine when they are connected individually; however, if I connect them both at once, the mouse does not work at all, even though it is detected during boot and there are not any error messages. Both devices are connected to a **self-powered USB hub**.

I read something that said the RPi had problems when both a high and low speed device were connected at the same time, but there was a possible fix with a newer kernel/firmware. I have updated to the latest kernel and firmware using `rpi-update`, but the problem still exists. I also tried another suggestion which was plugging one device into the hub and the other directly into the RPi, but still no luck.

Is there something else I can try to get both of these working at the same time?

**dmesg output:**

```
[    3.988029] usb 1-1.3.1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    4.122236] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
[    4.145138] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.160450] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[    4.173086] usb 1-1.3.1: Manufacturer: PIXART
[    4.200932] input: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.0/input/input0
[    4.247448] generic-usb 0003:093A:2510.0001: input: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3.1/input0
.
.
.
[   64.971776] usb 1-1.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[   65.917781] usb 1-1.3.1: new low-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[   66.192502] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
[   66.192550] usb 1-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   66.192569] usb 1-1.3.1: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[   66.192583] usb 1-1.3.1: Manufacturer: PIXART
[   66.311300] input: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.1/1-1.3.1:1.0/input/input3
[   66.312980] generic-usb 0003:093A:2510.0004: input: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3.1/input0
```

**lsusb output:**

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
```

Comment: Does the mouse show up in dmesg, driver get loaded etc the same way? Is it listed in lsusb the same way as when it's working?

Comment: I have most recent kernel/firmware and I still have problems with low/full speed devices connected at the same time. The problem is not yet resolved in driver, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you clarify what "self-powered" means? Are you talking about a hub that uses its own, separate power supply - or one that is just powered from its connection from the Pi?

Comment: @XTL: I don't have access to it right now, but I will check when I get a chance.

Comment: @PhonicUK: I mean a hub that has its own power supply.

Comment: @XTL: The mouse is listed the same way in `lsusb` whether it is working or not. The mouse is also detected and the driver is loaded the same way in `dmesg`; however, when the WiFi adapter is connected as well, once everything has loaded it then displays a message saying "USB disconnect, device number 5" (which is the mouse) and then loads it all over again as a new device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a known problem; the USB firmware on the Raspberry Pi can't deal with low-speed and high-speed devices at the same time.

The wireless adaptor is a high-speed device and the mouse is a low-speed device, hence you have problems.

#### Solution

I'm not sure there is one yet - others may post one of course. The firmware is actively being worked on I believe, so hopefully it will be fixed over time.

Comment: It did seem to be fairly common in what I saw mentioned, but I was hoping someone had found a solution. I guess people are just running their RPi with either WiFi or a mouse, but not both?

Comment: You can probably find a high speed mouse... I use powerline networking and Ethernet myself.